# Modal within other modal on UIkit

Tags: modal-dialog, uikit

When I'm clicking on the second modal, the first modal disappears. However, I want to keep it open as well! Is this a way to disable that behavior?

I have also noticed that other frameworks such as Foundation have the same behavior.

Here's my code:

```
<a href="#my-id" data-uk-modal>Open Modal</a>
<div id="my-id" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog"> 
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> 
        <a href="#my-id2" data-uk-modal>Nested Modal</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="my-id2" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog"> 
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davis88/6g80c1nf/6/).

Answer (score 6):

You can show multiple Modals using `uk-modal="stack: true"`

Here is the code

```
<button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-small-right" type="button" data-uk-toggle="target: #modal-example-1">Open</button>

<!-- This is the Parent modal -->
<div id="modal-example-1" uk-modal>
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Parent Modal</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p class="uk-text-right">
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button">Save</button>
        </p>
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin-small-right" type="button" data-uk-toggle="target: #modal-example-2">Open</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is the Child modal -->
<div id="modal-example-2" uk-modal="stack: true">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
        <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Child Modal</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer! Stack modals, when more than one is open. By default, the previous modal will be hidden. https://getuikit.com/docs/modal#component-options

Answer (score 4):

From documentation:

> You can trigger a new modal inside the current modal. The default behaviour closes the first modal when a second one opens. You can prevent this from happening by adding the `data-uk-modal="{target:'#ID',modal:false}"` attribute.

So something like:

```
<div>
    <h2>Multiple Modal</h2>
    <button class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal1', modal: false}">Open Modal 1</button>

</div>

<!-- This is the modal 1-->
<div id="modal1" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <h2>Modal 1</h2>
        <button class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal2', modal: false}">Open Modal 2</button>      
    </div>
</div>


<!-- This is the modal 2-->
<div id="modal2" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <h2>Modal 2</h2>
        <a class="uk-modal-close" href="#">Close Modal 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

should work.

I have it working with javascript:

```
var modal1 = UIkit.modal("#modal1", {center: true, modal: false}),
    modal2 = UIkit.modal("#modal2", {modal: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have do some changes :

Your HTML code :

```
<a href="#my-id" data-uk-modal >Open Modal</a>
<div id="my-id" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog"> 
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> 
        <a href="#my-id2" data-uk-modal>Nested Modal</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="my-id2" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog"> 
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery code should like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.UIkit.modal('#my-id').show();
    $.UIkit.modal('#my-id2').show();  

});
```

This should work

Comment: I tried what you proposed but it didn't work. See the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/davis88/6g80c1nf/9/embedded/result/).

Comment: nah.. if you remove the jquery lines, it will work ;p

Answer (score 0):

I have post new code that works, so please try this : It will work

```
<div>
    <h2>Multiple Modal</h2>
    <button class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal1'}">Open Modal 1</button>

</div>

<!-- This is the modal 1-->
<div id="modal1" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <h2>Modal 1</h2>
        <button class="uk-button" data-uk-modal="{target:'#modal2'}">Open Modal 2</button>      
    </div>
</div>


<!-- This is the modal 2-->
<div id="modal2" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <h2>Modal 2</h2>
        <a class="uk-modal-close" href="#">Close Modal 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should work...

Comment: Again, this doesn't work because the first modal disappears when you click on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

To overlay two Modallayer use the following code in Uikit3, if you open the Modals with JQuery:

UIkit.modal("#yourmodalid", {center: true, stack: true}).show();

This leaves the first Modallayer open.

Comment: Existing answers already cover this, and jQuery has nothing to do with it