# Open multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals and a button inside the first modal to open the second modal.
What I need is to open the second modal without closing the first.

```
modalOne = UIkit.modal("#modal_1");
modalTwo = UIkit.modal("#modal_2");

modalOne.on({

    'show.uk.modal': function(){
        alert("Modal one is visible."); 
    },

    'hide.uk.modal': function(){

    }
});

modalTwo.on({

        'show.uk.modal': function(){
            alert("Modal Two is visible."); 
        },

        'hide.uk.modal': function(){

        }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you'll have some answers on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159929/modal-within-other-modal-on-uikit

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for.